# How to get the same result as a array but without the third brackets?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function which removes elements from an object which looks like this :

```
 var remove = function(obj, props) {
   for(var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { 
       if(obj.hasOwnProperty(props[i])) { 
           delete obj[props[i]]; 
       }; 
   }; 
 };
```

Lets consider an object with some element :

```
 var obj = {
   one: "I am One",
   two: "I am Two"
 };
```

So, to remove the "one" & "two" elements from the object "obj" I have to call the following code :

```
 remove( obj, ["one", "two"]);
```

I have to use third brackets ( [] ) in order to write the elements but I want the code to be written something like this :

```
 remove( obj, "one", "two" );
```

Without the third brackets. But I don't understand where to update the code to get result like the example given above such that it supports the old browsers. Can you help ? Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can use the ECMA6 spread operator in function arguments (...props) or the function arguments themselves.

```js
var remove = function(obj) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(arguments[i])) {
      delete obj[arguments[i]];
    };
  };
};

var obj = {
  one: "I am One",
  two: "I am Two",
  three: "I am Three"
};

remove(obj, "one", "two");

console.info(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) : `var remove = function(obj, ...props)`

```js
var remove = function(obj, ...props) {
  console.log(props); // ["two", "three"]
  for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(props[i])) {
      delete obj[props[i]];
    }
  }
};

var obj = {
  one: "I am One",
  two: "I am Two"
};

remove(obj, "two", "three");

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let toBeDeleted_Object = ["one", "two"];
remove( obj, toBeDeleted_Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

1. Using Javascript Arguments object: [Reference Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

   ```
   var remove = function(obj) {

   // start loop from index: 1 as first element will be obj itself

   for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { 
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(arguments[i])) { 
          delete obj[arguments[i]]; 
      }; 
   };
   ```

   };
2. Using Javascript Spread operator syntax: [Reference Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
    var remove = function(obj, ...props) {
       for(var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { 
           if(obj.hasOwnProperty(props[i])) { 
               delete obj[props[i]]; 
           }; 
       }; 
     };
```